# convert pandas dataframe to a nested json

Tags: python, json, pandas, nested

I have a dataframe that looks like the following, with a column containing an already nested list of dictionaries:

```
import pandas as pd

data = {'First':  ['First value', 'Second value'],
    'Second': ['First value', 'Second value'],
    'third': ['First value', 'Second value'],
    'forth': ['[{"values": "","entity": "datetime","","Turn":  [{"expression": "","tid": "","type": "", "value": "","mod": "","anchor": "","beginPoint": "","endPoint": ""}]}]','[{"values": "","entity": "datetime","Turn": [{"expression": "","tid": "","type": "", "value": "","mod": "","anchor": "","beginPoint": "","endPoint": ""}]}]'],
    }

df = pd.DataFrame (data, columns = ['First','second','third','forth'])
```

I would like to convert it to the following json format and save it as such:

```
[
  {
    "first": "",
    "second": "",
    "third": "",
    "forth": [
        {
          "values": "",
          "entity": "",
          "TIMEX3": [
            {
              "expression": "",
              "tid": "",
              "type": "",
              "value": "",
              "mod": "",
              "anchorTimeID": "",
              "beginPoint": "",
              "endPoint": ""
                    }
                  ]
                }
              ]
            },...
```

I have tried the following, but the output is too messy and it does not look like the output I would like to save

```
  my_json = (df.groupby(['text','intent','domain'], as_index=False)
               .apply(lambda x: x[['entities']].to_dict('r'))
               .reset_index()
               .to_json(orient='records',indent= 2))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe, you're not that far from the format you want.  The only issue was column `forth` contains the dictionary as a string.  One possible approach is to convert everything back to dictionary, use eval to convert the string back to the dictionary, and use a json parser to print it nicely:

```
import pandas as pd
import json

data = {'First':  ['First value', 'Second value'],
    'Second': ['First value', 'Second value'],
    'third': ['First value', 'Second value'],
    'forth': ['[{"values": "","entity": "datetime","Turn":  [{"expression": "","tid": "","type": "", "value": "","mod": "","anchor": "","beginPoint": "","endPoint": ""}]}]','[{"values": "","entity": "datetime","Turn": [{"expression": "","tid": "","type": "", "value": "","mod": "","anchor": "","beginPoint": "","endPoint": ""}]}]'],
    }
df = pd.DataFrame (data, columns = ['First','Second','third','forth'])

my_dict = df.to_dict(orient='records')
for row in my_dict:
    row['forth'] = eval(row['forth'])
my_json = json.dumps(my_dict, indent=2)
print(my_json)
```

There are two small corrections, a capitalization on the `Second` key, and an invalid entry: `, "",`  in your `forth` key.

Here is a copy of my output:

```
[
  {
    "First": "First value",
    "Second": "First value",
    "third": "First value",
    "forth": [
      {
        "values": "",
        "entity": "datetime",
        "Turn": [
          {
            "expression": "",
            "tid": "",
            "type": "",
            "value": "",
            "mod": "",
            "anchor": "",
            "beginPoint": "",
            "endPoint": ""
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  },  ...
```

If column `forth` is already a dictionary in the dataframe, you can call `to_json` directly and the formatting will be what you desired.  As an example you can try converting back the corrected `my_dict` into dataframe:

```
test_df = pd.DataFrame(my_dict)
print(test_df.to_json(orient='records', indent=2))
```